# My ASP.NET application doesn't show filled GridView after collecting data from MySql database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net, gridview

I've got a GridView. My application connects to MySql database, collects data and it should display it in GridView, but it doesn't. When I do it the same way in Windows Forms application - it fills DataGridView and there is no problem. But when I run my ASP.NET application in any browser - it shows label and button, but when I click "Fill grid" button - it doesn't show the GridView. I copied MySql.Data.dll and System.Data.dll to "bin" directory. There's no compilation error. Connection string is ok.

This is my ASP.NET application:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient" %>
<%@ Assembly Name = "MySql.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace = "System.Data" %>
<%@ Assembly Name = "System.Data" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">

    protected void btnFillData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Database=autolot;Uid=root;Pwd=pass;");
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from inventory;", conn);
        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
        conn.Close();
        carsGridView.DataSource = dt;
        carsGridView.DataBind();
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblInfo" runat="server" 
            Text="Click on the button to fill the grid">
        </asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="carsGridView" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnFillData" runat="server" Text="Fill grid" />    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to debug your code using break-points weather your reader has some values or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like the click handler is actually *assigned* to the button's click event.  So the button is causing a post-back, but not invoking the handler.  (I bet if you debug the current code you'll find that the `btnFillData_Click` method is never even invoked.)

Try assigning it explicitly:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnFillData" runat="server" Text="Fill grid" OnClick="btnFillData_Click" />
```

Comment: I'm so amateur... I should have noticed that. Should I delete my question?

Comment: @BlackCamel: Not at all, it's a perfectly reasonable question which could potentially serve to help others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't assign the function to the button on the HTML code, you need to add `OnClick="btnFillData_Click"` to the button Tag